# how to merge two dataframes according to date

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames, one looks like:
[image]
And another that looks like:

[image]

I'm getting an error when I try to merge the two dataframes using pd.merge
The error is "value error: you are trying to merge on datetime64[ns] and int64 columns".  How do I get around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to have the same dtype for both columns. So convert the first date to a year, and the merge should then be fine.

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.year)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df=df.merge(df1,how='left')
```